# Can't use State var within sheet modifier SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I select a cell, I simply set the `selectedPlayer` object and toggle the boolean to show the dialog.

When the sheet modifier is activated, there are a few issues:

1. `selectedPlayer` is nil
2. The sheet modifier is called 4 times
3. The sheet is presented 4 times

What am I doing wrong? I'm guessing the body is regenerated twice because I'm modifying 2 State variables, but why isn't `selectedPlayer` correct, and why is the modifier called 4 times?

```swift
struct PlayerListingView: View {

    @State private var selectedPlayer: PlayerEntity?
    @State private var showAddPlayer: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            ForEach(players) { player in
                playerCell(player, onSelect: { p in
                    selectedPlayer = p
                    printv("cell selected selectedPlayer: \(selectedPlayer)")
                    showAddPlayer.toggle()
                })
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddPlayer) {
            printv("selectedPlayer: \(selectedPlayer)")
            EditPlayerView(isPresented: $showAddPlayer, player: selectedPlayer)
        }
    }
```

The result is:

```
cell selected selectedPlayer: Optional(<PlayerEntity: 0x600001a46440> (entity: PlayerEntity; id: 0xd30220ea8e2e9274 <x-coredata://3BBD8F8D-C878-4108-80BF-02ADECE684C2/PlayerEntity/p1>; data: {
    email = "my email";
    games = "<relationship fault: 0x60000393f180 'games'>";
    id = "BDB08E37-16B4-4372-9D31-18220405E1B1";
    "name_" = "my name";
    teams = "<relationship fault: 0x60000393f160 'teams'>";
}))
selectedPlayer: nil
selectedPlayer: nil
selectedPlayer: nil
selectedPlayer: nil
2021-10-22 08:59:41.845954-0500 app[75686:6355985] Writing analzed variants.
2021-10-22 08:59:42.447861-0500 app[75686:6355985] [Presentation] Attempt to present <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7ff21b718230> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x7ff1fc007150> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentGS1_VVS_22_VariadicView_Children7ElementVS_24NavigationColumnModifier_GVS_18StyleContextWriterVS_19SidebarStyleContext___: 0x7ff21b70c8e0>) which is already presenting <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7ff21d323ac0>.
2021-10-22 08:59:42.448226-0500 app[75686:6355985] [Presentation] Attempt to present <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7ff21b719c80> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x7ff1fc007150> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentGS1_VVS_22_VariadicView_Children7ElementVS_24NavigationColumnModifier_GVS_18StyleContextWriterVS_19SidebarStyleContext___: 0x7ff21b70c8e0>) which is already presenting <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7ff21d323ac0>.
2021-10-22 08:59:42.448574-0500 app[75686:6355985] [Presentation] Attempt to present <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7ff21d326920> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x7ff1fc007150> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentGS1_VVS_22_VariadicView_Children7ElementVS_24NavigationColumnModifier_GVS_18StyleContextWriterVS_19SidebarStyleContext___: 0x7ff21b70c8e0>) which is already presenting <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7ff21d323ac0>.
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: What's `printv`?

Comment: A simple helper function so I can print within ViewBuilders: ```func printv( _ data : Any) -> EmptyView { print(data); return EmptyView() }```

Comment: `The sheet is presented 4 times` - is this visible on the screen, or it's a conclusion from the logs? Note that SwiftUI can call the blocks you provided many times, however the UI output will not necessarily change.

Comment: Yes, it's from the logs. Just seems very wasteful, thought I was doing something inefficiently. The final result is fine, but some views create other objects that just seem unnecessary. For example, if the selectedPlayer is nil, I create a new player within the `EditPlayerView` on a child context. Four new core data objects get created...

Comment: This is the reason why you should put the data management code in a (View)Model class. Views are created and discarded many times during the app lifecycle, so unless you write complicated code along the `onAppear`/`onDisappear`, you might end up with some unexpected situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can present a sheet by toggling a boolean

```
func sheet<Content>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>,...
```

or by selecting an item

```
func sheet<Item, Content>(item: Binding<Item?>,...
```

but not both simultaneously. If you want to proceed with the selected item use **only** the latter form and delete the `Bool`

```
struct PlayerListingView: View {

    @State private var selectedPlayer: PlayerEntity?
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            ForEach(players) { player in
                playerCell(player, onSelect: { p in
                    selectedPlayer = p
                    printv("cell selected selectedPlayer: \(selectedPlayer)")
                  
                })
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedPlayer) {
            printv("selectedPlayer: \(selectedPlayer)")
            EditPlayerView(player: selectedPlayer)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't use the item-based modifier because selectedPlayer can be nil and passed to the `EditPlayerView` dialog (which represents creating a new player). I'd rather just use the Bool-based approach. Are there known issues with using sheets like this?

Comment: I am probably not understanding at a fundamental level what's going on with the sheet modifier. It sounds like it's using captured values within it's content callback? In that case it makes sense why you suggested using a `Binding` to an item instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is pretty unintuitive and left me confused for a while... if I updated other state before updating selectedPlayer, why would that also not be reflected in the .sheet() callback?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this based on @vadian's feedback:

```swift
struct PlayerListingView: View {
    @FetchRequest var players: FetchedResults<PlayerEntity>

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var managedObjectContext

    @State private var selectedPlayer: PlayerEntity?
    @State private var showAddPlayer: Bool = false

    init() {
        _players = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: PlayerEntity.fetchRequestWithPredicate())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(header) {
            ForEach(players) { player in
                playerCell(player, onSelect: { p in
                    selectedPlayer = p
                })
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedPlayer) { item in
            EditPlayerView(player: item) {
                selectedPlayer = nil
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddPlayer) {
            EditPlayerView(player: nil) {
                showAddPlayer.toggle()
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```