# Bindings from the sheet modifier

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am using the SwiftUI sheet modifier on a View that has a collection published from its view model. When a user clicks on a list item, I am setting an optional State value to the corresponding item from the list. The sheet modifier uses the $selectedSubscription value to present and hide the sheet when needed, and passes the value to the closure in order for me to use it in a details view. I have set up the details view to receive a @Binding to a list item in order to edit it at a later stage. The problem is that SwiftUI will not let me pass the item in the closure as a binding.

```
struct SubscriptionsListView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm = SubscriptionsListVM()
    
    @State private var selectedSubscription: PVSubscription? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ...
            }
            .sheet(item: $selectedSubscription) { subscription in
                SubscriptionDetailsView(subscription: $subscription) <--- error here
                    .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubscriptionDetailsView: View {

@Binding var subscription: PVSubscription

...

}
```

I already tried to get the index of the item from the array and to pass that as a binding, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: You could try `SubscriptionDetailsView(subscription: $selectedSubscription)` with `@Binding var subscription: PVSubscription?`.

Comment: I tried that but it is an optional and I did not find the syntax to force unwrap it (Given the fact that it must have a value if we are in that code block)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Does your "PVSubscription" enum conform to the "Identifiable" protocol?

Comment: Yes, it does, the error says it can not find subscription in scope.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the use of the sheet modifier. You are trying to use the "selectedSubscription" variable both for showing a sheet and showing the details of your model. You have to create another variable for showing the sheet.

Since your sheet only shows one view, you don't need the sheet modifier with the item argument. Item argument is used for showing different views in the same sheet modifier (settings, profile etc.). It doesn't give you a binding in the trailing closure to put into the subview.

```
struct SubscriptionsListView: View {

    @StateObject var vm = SubscriptionsListVM()

    @State private var selectedSubscription: PVSubscription? = nil

    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ... // Toggle show sheet here
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                SubscriptionDetailsView(subscription: $selectedSubscription)
                    .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I do not believe that using the bool variant of the sheet works in this case because the details page uses items from a list and when setting the selectedItem on tap the details screen will not always have the intended item.
Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69678322/cant-use-state-var-within-sheet-modifier-swiftui